# Manually Save CSV Data from Excel without blank lines

Tags: excel, export-to-csv

I have a two tab Excel spreadsheet. The first tab has a query that is run against an ODBC connection to get the current list of users for a system from that systems database. The second tab has a formula in each cell that copies the data from the first tab making various adjustments so the resulting data can be submitted to our audit website that ensures users are current and active in our various systems.
The issue is because I copied the formula down well passed the number of rows that we typically get back for the active users the end of the CSV file is fill of lines with only commas.

```
,,,,,,
```

Obviously, I am manually removing these extra lines at this point which is not too difficult. Is there a way to tell Excel when I am saving tab as a CSV file to not include the rows where the formula does not bring any data back?